# How can we remove square brackets [] and double quotes "" in angular js?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can I remove `Square Brackets []` and `Double quotes ""` in repeated answer, [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJ9THSb0VFV2JIjm3AKu) actually we need show `role` vlaues in my app so we have used `ng-repeat="mani in name.comments "` to get the answer,  and we got the answer like `["user"]`, `["admin"]`, `["kp"]` , what we exactly looking we just need to show the values alone, not with the `[] Square Brackets` and `Double quotes`.... **for example answer would be**:-  values are without in `[] Square Brackets` and `Double quotes` like `1. user , 2. admin, 3. kp`

**My Data:-**

```
$scope.name = {
"_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",

"comments": [
{
"created": 1485511936350,
"role": [
"user"
],
"email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
"name": "selvam R",
"commentText": "mani selvam"
},
{
"created": 1485511936350,
"role": [
"admin"
],
"email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
"name": "selvam R",
"commentText": "mani selvam"
},
{
"created": 1485511936350,
"role": [
"kp"
],
"email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
"name": "selvam R",
"commentText": "mani selvam"
}
],
"created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z",
"isCurrentUserOwner": false
};
```

**My Html:-**

```
<div ng-repeat="mani in name.comments ">

                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{mani.role }}</td>

              </div>
```

- Please look at into  [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJ9THSb0VFV2JIjm3AKu) for reference  ...
- Expecting answer would be without `[] Square Brackets` and `Double quotes`...
- This `role`  are within the array so that only it's showing with `[] Square Brackets` and `Double quotes` , so how can we remove this , we need to show only values... we have tried many ways we know it's simple task but we unable to solve this issue..
- can we use css to remove this ?... any one knows the solution please help us... thanks
- please update plunker as well to know the exact solution....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to select the first element of the array at index 0 using:

`{{ mani.role[0] }}`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
    "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",

    "comments": [{
      "created": 1485511936350,
      "role": [
        "user"
      ],
      "email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
      "name": "selvam R",
      "commentText": "mani selvam"
    }, {
      "created": 1485511936350,
      "role": [
        "admin"
      ],
      "email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
      "name": "selvam R",
      "commentText": "mani selvam"
    }, {
      "created": 1485511936350,
      "role": [
        "kp"
      ],
      "email": "selvam@e21designs.com",
      "name": "selvam R",
      "commentText": "mani selvam"
    }],
    "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z",
    "isCurrentUserOwner": false
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="mani in name.comments ">

    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{ mani.role[0] }}</td>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `toString()` method to convert the array that is being displayed to a string. Like so:

```
        <td>{{mani.role.toString()}}</td>
```

That will display it as a string so the `"` and `[]` will be removed.

[Plunkr showing this.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NIOHPES8mEHlj00KXkE3)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mani.role` is an array, so do something like this:

```
<td><span ng-repeat="r in mani.role">{{ r }} </span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like Json data, so what you need is to read Json data through AngularJS by creating module like this:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.data = res.data;                
        });
});
```

Also, w3schools helpful in your case [$http in AngularJS](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)